# When is a UITextField's text property set?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

I've been having an interesting problem. I've got both a `UIButton` and a `UITextField`, lets call them `myButton` and `myField` respectively. Now, when the user presses `myButton`, it is supposed to save the contents of `[myField text]` to another variable that we'll call `otherVar`. Now when I type into `myField` and hit the return key, everything works fine, however when I press `myButton` before `myField` has been left, the string that gets stored in `otherVar` always looks something like:

```
<UIButtonContent: 0x4e13c60 Title = (null), Image = <UIImage: 0x4b50980>, Background = (null), TitleColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 1 1, ShadowColor = UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 0.5>
```

Does the [myField text] not get set until the user presses the return key, leaving the text field? And also, is there a way to tell if the user has left `myField` before pressing `myButton`?

Here is the IBAction code for `myButton`:

```
-(IBAction)myButton:(id)sender{
    if (![[myField text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [[[appDelegate moduleList] objectAtIndex:[appDelegate moduleNum]] setOtherVar:[myField text]];
     }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: added the IBAction for `myButton`

Comment: you should use `isEqualToString:` to compare strings

Comment: You're right, thank you. However, upon making said change, the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `[myField resignFirstResponder];` before your if statement in the `IBAction` method. This should commit any of the text edits that have been made, and populate the `text` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use notifications to know exactly when a `UITextField` has changed its value, discussed [in the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3).

More about notifications [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html).

There are also delegate methods for `UITextFields` which let you know when editing begins and ends, among other things - [docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).